# enum or char(1) in MySQL

Tags: mysql, performance

Sometimes I am not sure whether using enum or char(1) in MysQL. For instance, I store statuses of posts. Normally, I only need **`Active`** or **`Passive`** values in `status` field. I have two options:

```
// CHAR
status char(1);

// ENUM (but too limited)
status enum('A', 'P');
```

What about if I want to add one more status type (ie. `Hidden`) in the future? If I have small data, it won't be an issue. But if i have too large data, so editing ENUM type will be problem, i think.

So what's your advice if we also think about MySQL performance? Which way I would go?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Neither. You'd typically use tinyint with a lookup table

- char(1) will be slightly slower because comparing uses collation
- confusion: As you extend to more than A and P
- using a letter limits you as you add more types. See last point.
- every system I've seen has more then one client eg reporting. A and P have to resolved to Active and Passive for in each client code
- extendibility: add one more type ("S" for "Suspended") you can one row to a lookup table or change a lot of code and constraints. And your client code too
- maintenance: logic is in 3 places: database constraint, database code and client code. With a lookup and foreign key, it can be in one place
- Enum is not portable

On the plus side of using a single letter or Enum

Note: there is a related DBA.SE [MySQL question about Enums](https://dba.stackexchange.com/q/6962/630). The recommendation is to use a lookup table there too.

Comment: if i am having one column as gender char(1) , how would i change it into gender enum('m','f','o') in mysql ? Is this possible ?

Answer (score 2):

You can use

```
status enum('Active', 'Passive');
```

It will not save a string in the row, it will only save a number that is reference to enum member in the table structure, so the size is the same but its more readable than `char(1)` or your `enum`.
Editing enum is not a problem no matter how big your data is

Comment: if you are right about *editing ENUM is not a problem no matter how big  your data is...* so that's the answer

Comment: Regarding the statement that "Editing enum is not a problem no matter how big your data is", that's not always true. If you are using MySQL 5.0, then changing the enum values requires a table rebuild. If you are using 5.1, 5.5, etc then a rebuild is not always necessary, but sometimes it is. Check the manual: http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/alter-table.html

Comment: If you edit the definition of an enum and add an extra element to it, the table needs altering, which can potentially take a long time depending on the size of your table - I've seen it take a while before, it's certainly not instantaneous...

Comment: if i am having one column as gender char(1) , how would i change it into gender enum('m','f','o') in mysql ? Is this possible ?

Answer (score 1):

I would use a binary `SET` field for this, but without labelling the options specifically within the database. All the "labelling" would be done within your code, but it does provide some very flexible options.

For example, you could create a `SET` containing eight "options" such as;

```
`column_name` SET('a', 'b', 'c', 'd', 'e', 'f', 'g', 'h') NOT NULL DEFAULT ''
```

Within your application, you can then define the 'a' as denoting "Active" or "Passive", the 'b' can denote "Hidden", and the rest can be left undefined until you need them.

You can then use all sorts of useful binary operations on the field for instance you could extract all those which are "Hidden" by running;

```
WHERE `column_name` & 'b'
```

And all those which are "Active" AND "Hidden" by running;

```
WHERE `column_name` & 'a' AND `column_name` & 'b'
```

You can even use the `LIKE` and `FIND_IN_SET` operators to do even more useful queries.

Read the MySQL documentation for further information;

http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/set.html

Hope it helps!

Dave

Comment: NP :) See how you get on. If you understand the boolean logic operators for AND (&) and OR (|) things can get really clever! In the example above, a=1, b=2, c=4, d=8, etc, so if ONLY a and b are set, you can just do `column_name` = 3 to get those where ONLY a and b are set and none others. Etc...

Answer (score 0):

Hard to tell without knowing the semantics of your statuses, but to me "hidden" doesn't seem like an alternative to "active" or "passive", i.e. you might want to have both "active hidden" and "passive hidden"; this would degenerate with each new non-exclusive "status", it would be better to implement your schema with boolean flags: one for the active/passive distinction, and one for the hidden/visible distinction. Queries become more readable when your condition is "WHERE NOT hidden" or "WHERE active", instead of "WHERE status = 'A'".

Comment: Thanks for thought. Hidden is just an example. What is your advice? I think, CHAR(1) is the best. Because it's human-readable, 1 byte and flexible, right?

Comment: My advice is what I said above: use boolean columns. Boolean is equivalent to tinyint(1) in mysql, as for storage it's almost the same as char(1); performance-wise, I have no idea how optimized comparison against char(1) columns is in mysql, it might be equivalent too, or comparing char(1) could be more expensive than comparing tinyint(1). There is not much chance for tinyint(1) comparisons being slower than char(1) comparisons.

`create table post (...your columns..., is_active bool not null default true, is_hidden bool not null default false);`