# Better type for storing 2 different single char

Tags: postgresql, postgresql-9.2

When in column must be stored only 2 values: `0` or `1`,

What is the best column type choice for this column: `"char"` or `ENUM('0', '1')`?

Comment: So a boolean type? http://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.1/static/datatype-boolean.html

Comment: How soon will you need to add more possibilities to the list?

Comment: @Jonathan Leffler  Only this possibilities will stay always

Comment: Looks like a duplicate of [this question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8038305/enum-or-char1-in-mysql) The answer is quite comprehensive, have a look You should also have look at this [enum vs integer](http://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/6962/advantages-and-disadvantages-to-using-enum-vs-integer-types) question on db.stackexchange for a more comprehensive database related answer. Make sure you check out the links on the accepted answer.

Comment: So is this a C-style boolean? Are they characters that just happen to be the number characters 0 and 1? Are they really the numbers 0 and 1? The answer (IMO) is to store them as what they really are and add CHECK constraints and such to ensure that the values are valid (or a custom domain).

Comment: @Flexo: The suggested "duplicate" is **not a duplicate at all**. PostgreSQL offers different options than MySQL. In particular, PostgreSQL has a proper, SQL standard compliant [**`boolean`**](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/interactive/datatype-boolean.html) type, which should be used here.

Comment: @erw sorry about that, reopened.

Answer (score 1):

As mentioned in the comments, this should be neither `char` nor `enum`, but a [`boolean`](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/interactive/datatype-boolean.html).

`FALSE` translates to `0`.
`TRUE` translates to`1`.
If you want to disallow `NULL` values define the column `NOT NULL`.